Expo not importing com.google.gms.google-services into android project on build
I am trying to set up an simple android expo application using react-native-firebase. I've been trying to set up the auth screen but I keep hitting this error:

No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()

I'm pretty new to this, but I thought this error was only present when using the firebase sdk and not the react native firebase SDK.
After looking at my build.gradle for adroid I can see that it is missing the plugin import listed in the docs:

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

My app.json looks as follows:
  {
  "expo": {
    "name": "appName",
    "slug": "appName",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.[redacted].wordjournal",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "output": "static",
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios":{
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "experiments": {
      "typedRoutes": true
    }
  }
}

According to the docs I should be able to configure something in this config file to have the plugin imported into the android project but I can't figure out how.
Any help or a link to an existing project that just has this sort of setup I could copy would be appreciated.
Thanks
Update
I recreated the entire project and now it works. Still no clue why I was hitting this.
